# Determine the shape of curve which has the minimum number of inflection points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $A$  be a set of generic $C^2$  closed curves in $2$-dimentional Euclidean space, and an equivalence relation between $2$ curves $a$ and $b$ in $A$ is defind that there exist diffeomorpfic map $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$   which satisfies $h \circ a=b$ .

An inflection point of curve in $A$ is a point which curvature is $0$. For example, the curve $(x,y)=(cos(t),sin(t-\frac{\pi}{4}))$ is figure-eight curve and it has 2 inflection points.

For example, curve $c$ and $d$ is equivalent.
$c$ has $2$ inflection points.
On the other hand, $d$ has no inflection points.

http://ks.c.yimg.jp/res/chie-reply-12-1/1/090/069/i320

My question is
"Given a curve $e$ below. Determine the curve which is equivalent to $e$ and has minimum number of inflection points."

http://ks.c.yimg.jp/res/chie-que-12140/12/140/075/412/iraw

The method proposed by Masaaki Umehara arxiv.org/abs/1103.3343 costs nonpolynomial time (tremendous time) to calculate. Please answer the minimum number and your algorithm of determination.

Comment: Polynomial in what? BTW, is this a question on differential geometry or on complexity?

Comment: When the curve $a$ in $A$ has $m$ double points, it takes more than $3^m$ checks to determine by using known algorithm.